# Permute string until it matches some input?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

I've looked this up online without much results because it's quite hard to describe in a few words.

Basically, I need to have a function, say `puntil` which takes the argument `string`. Basically, the function permutes until the string is equal to the argument.

For example if you run `puntil('ab')` it should do inside the function:

a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
aa
**ab** !! MATCH

Another example, for `puntil('abcd')` it will do

a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
af
ag
ah
ai
aj
ak
al
am
an
ao
ap
aq
ar
as
at
au
av
aw
ax
ay
az

... etc etc ..
until it matches abcd.

*Basically an infinite permutation until it matches.*

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe your problem clearly?

Comment: @F.Ju Match every possible string in the universe until it matches some input.

Comment: I think it is very clear.

Comment: So, what will be the o/p? Number of terms before the i/p string or we need to print all strings before we get the matched string?

Comment: @vish4071 input and output?

Comment: the input will be something like "hello". I don't really need an output, just a way to actually do it. Store it in an array, say.

Comment: What I meant was, if your input is `ab`, what should your function print/return? A number 28, as `ab is 28th string` or `a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa ab`

Comment: @vish4071 ok, just implement as you describe, what's your goal ? or what you need is how to implement?

Comment: @vish4071 Sure, do it the second way. Again, I have my own use for this but I'm just looking for a way to actually loop through all the possibilities.

Comment: Oh come on guys! OP describes what he need to do very clearly.

Comment: i had fun doing this! cool challenge, was a bit trickier than I initially thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlie2002/xbgb5fzf/)

```
 var alphabet = ['a','b','c'];//,'d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

 var output = "";
 var match = "cccc";  //<----------- match here

//This is your main function 
function permutate() {

    var d = 0;   // d for depth

    while (true) {

       //Your main alphabet iteration             
       for (var i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++){

          //First level 
          if (d === 0) {
             console.log(alphabet[i])
             output = alphabet[i];
          }    
          else
             iterator(alphabet[i], d);   //Call iterator for d > 0

          if (output === match)
             return;
          }


          d++;  //Increase the depth
       }
 }


 //This function runs n depths of iterations
 function iterator(s, depth){

    if (depth === 0)
       return;

    for (var i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++){

       if (depth > 1)
          iterator(s + alphabet[i], depth - 1)
       else {
          console.log(s + alphabet[i]);
          output = s + alphabet[i];
       } 

       if (output === match)
          return;
    }

 };
```

Explanation:

Your program needs to traverse a tree of alphabet like this

```
[a] 
    -[a]
        -[a] 
             -[a]...
             -[b]...

         [b] ...
    -[b] -
         -[a]...
         -[b]...

[b] - ...
[c] - ...
```

This could have easily been done through a conventional recursive function if not for the requirement that you need to finish each depth first.

So we need a special `iterator(s, depth)` function which can perform number of nested iterations (depth) requested.

So the main function can call the iterator with increasing depths (d++).

That's all!!

*Warning: This is a prototype only. This can be optimized and improved. It uses global variables for the ease of demonstrating. Your real program should avoid globals. Also I recommend calling the `iterator()` inside `setTimeout` if your match word is too long.
The `n` depths can only be limited by your resources.*

Comment: Thanks, this is really nice! I appreciate the Efforts ! :D

Comment: Avoid using globals. Let the iterator function has it's own alphabet array. It's totally worth it. Also pass the match word along the argument list. Hint: You can even make this code shorter. I broke the 1st level and the rest for the ease of explaining. Thanks for posting this. I had real fun.

Answer (score 2):

What OP is asking is a bit ambiguous, so I'll post for both the things (that I doubt) OP is asking.

First, the question can be, what will be the position of input string in the infinite permutation of alphabets (which I see as more legit question, I've given the reason later). This can be done in the following manner:

Taking an example (input = `dhca`). So, all strings of 1 to 3 characters length will come before this string. So, add: `26^1 + 26^2 + 26^3` to the answer. Then, 1st character is `d`, which means, following the dictionary, if 1st character is `a | b | c`, all characters past that are valid. So, add `3 * 26^3` to the answer. Now, say 1st character is `d`. Then, we can have all characters from `a to g (7)` and last 2 characters can be anything. So, add `7 * 26^2` to the answer. Going on in this way, we get the answer as:

```
26^1 + 26^2 + 26^3 + (3 * 26^3) + (7 * 26^2) + (2 * 26^1) + (0) + 1
= 75791
```

OK. Now the second thing, which I think OP is actually asking (to print all strings before we get a match). Now, why I think this is unfeasible is because if we have input as `zzzzz` (5 characters long) we need to print `26^1 + 26^2 + 26^3 + 26^4 + 26^5` strings, which is `12356630`. So, for this part, I assume max length of input string is 5 (And definitely no more) because for 6 character length string, we need to print ~321272406 strings --> NOT POSSIBLE.

So, a simple solution to this can be:

- Create an array of size 27 as: arr[] = {'', 'a', 'b', ..., 'y', 'z'}. 1st character is null.
- Write 5 (max string length) nested loops from 0 to 26 (inclusive) and add it to dummy string and print it. Something like.

  ```
  for i from 0 to 26
      String a = "" + arr[i]
      for j from 0 to 26
          String b = a + arr[j]
          for k from 0 to 26
              String c = b + arr[k]
              for l from 0 to 26
                  String d = c + arr[l]
                  for m from 0 to 26
                      String e = d + arr[m]
                      print e
                      if(e equals input string)
                          break from all loops //use some flag, goto statement etc.
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D. Anyway, how would you make this permutate WITHOUT USING the length of the input string? Like a blind permutation until it matches the input.

Comment: There is a better solution to this question than this answer. You can use recursive loop to get the result. The depth will only be limited by the system resources.

Comment: What your question asks is not exactly permutation. You have repeated characters and you need is dictionary occurance of the i/p string.

Comment: @bytec0de, I really don't understand what is the use case for all these strings for you. At the same time, you don't know what is the max length of the input...Even with the best of machines, for a string of length 7, like `zzzzzzz`, you need to print `8353082582` strings, which takes at least 100s. With a recursive code, as @CharlieH said, I don't think system stack allows depth of order 8 and we are talking order 10.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/afjbz6he/)

```
function next(charArray, rightBound){

    if(!rightBound){
        rightBound = charArray.length;
    }

    var oldValue = charArray[rightBound-1];
    var newValue = nextCharacter(charArray[rightBound-1]);
    charArray[rightBound-1] = newValue;

    if(newValue < oldValue){
        if(rightBound > 1){
            next(charArray, rightBound-1);
        }
        else{
            charArray.push('a');
        }
    }
    return charArray;
}

function nextCharacter(char){
    if(char === 'z'){
        return 'a'
    }
    else{
        return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
    }
}

function permuteUntil(word){
    var charArray = ['a'];
    var wordChain = ['a'];

    while(next(charArray).join('') !== word){
        wordChain.push(charArray.join(''));
    }

    wordChain.push(word);

    return wordChain.join(', ');
}


alert(permuteUntil('ab'));
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it... Any more elegant way, though?

Comment: I have updated the answer and the fiddle with cleaner code

Comment: Thanks! It looks like you got exactly what I need... please hold on while I test it for my application :D

Answer (score -1):

You asked for a more elegant solution, here's a simple function that converts integers into lowercase strings of characters allowing you to easily iterate through strings.

```
function toWord(val, first, out) {
if(first == 1)
    out = String.fromCharCode(97 + val % 26) + out;
else
    out = String.fromCharCode(97 + (val-1) % 26) + out;
if(val % 26 == 0 && first == 0) {
    val -= 26;
}
else {
    val -= val %26;
}
val = val / 26;
if(val != 0)
    return toWord(val, 0, out);
else
    return out;
}
```

It's by no means perfect, but it's short and simple. When calling the function set val to be the integer you want to convert, first as 1, and out as "".

For example the following will apply yourFunction to the first 10,000 lowercase strings

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    youFunction(toWord(i, 1, ""));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So you need to always start incrementing from `a`? Since they are char values you can easily do this with the following construct:

Note that this is a java solution :)

```
public static char[] increment(char[] arr, int pos) {
    // get current position char
    char currentChar = arr[pos];

    // increment it by one
    currentChar++;

    // if it is at the end of it's range
    boolean overflow = false;
    if (currentChar > 'Z') {
        overflow = true;
        currentChar = 'A';
    }

    // always update current char
    arr[pos] = currentChar;
    if (overflow) {
        if (pos == 0) {
            // resize array and add new character
            char[] newArr = new char[arr.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, newArr, 0, arr.length);
            newArr[arr.length] = 'A';

            arr = newArr;
        } else {
            // overflowed, increment one position back
            arr = increment(arr, pos - 1);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String stringToUse = "A";
    final String stringToSearch = "ABCD";

    char[] use = stringToUse.toCharArray();
    for (;;) {
        final String result = new String(use);

        System.out.println("Candidate: " + result);
        if (stringToSearch.equals(result)) {
            System.out.println("Found!");
            break;
        }

        use = increment(use, use.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, seems like this took some time to think out... i got no experience with java, but this helped visualize the flow. Thanks!

Comment: @bytec0de, awesome man, glad it helped, I had fun doing it as well